# How to play MP3 files into the microphone input jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, microphone

I am attempting to create it so when a user plays a sound, it plays the sound to the users microphone input.  Thus when they're in a Skype Call/Game chat/etc it will be played for all users to hear.

Is there any way to play music to the microphone instead of speakers in Javascript/jQuery?  If not, does node-webkit give me any more ability to do this?

Hopefully this is well explained, it is a little challenge.

Thanks for any, and all advise!

Comment: Won't any sounds coming out of the speakers enter the microphone anyway? Albeit with the room noises too.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible from the web browser alone.  Most systems aren't even capable of this directly.

It is up to the client to decide how to route audio and there is no control of this within the browser, except for what happens within the page itself.

The best you can do is to recommend to your users how to configure their systems.  For your Windows users, they will need a virtual audio loopback driver.  http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Cable/

Comment: Interesting, although that kind of sucks.  Thanks for the info!