# How to play an mp3 or wav file directly into my own microphone without it playing through my speakers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, microphone

I need to play an file which can either be mp3 or wav directly into  my microphone. I cannot have it playing through my speakers though.

I have done some research and found that a module named `sounddevice` was meant to help but it was not clear on how I would do this.

**I do not care how many dependencies there are, I just want to play an mp3 or wav directly into my microphone without it playing in my speakers.**

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It seems that you need a virtual microphone device, right? Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37055745/playing-mp3-file-through-microphone-with-python) help you?

Comment: Yes it does, thank you! I saw this post before but only read the accepted answer, which did not help me but another did! @whilrun :)