# Is there a way to imitate sound input with python?

Tags: python, audio

I wanted to make a program that would pass some sound data to the system's microphone, imitating person's speech. Originally I wanted it to "talk" in a discord voice chat to other people, but I couldn't find any way to do so.

I tried libraries like SoundCard and PyAudio, but they seem to only have functions to either get the mic input from the user, or to output sound via speakers. However, I want it to **simulate** microphone input.

So, is there any way to do this with python (or any other language)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Playing mp3 file through microphone with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37055745/playing-mp3-file-through-microphone-with-python)

Comment: Someone asked this recently, here's how that went: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65796932/pass-audio-file-as-microphone-input-with-python?noredirect=1#comment116398362_65796932