# Play audio file through microphone using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyaudio

I want to play audio through a virtual microphone I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61674334/16838936) but you can't install that version of pygame anymore. I have tried installing older/earlier versions but there was no output.

Sounddevice (I believe) only works with output devices:

```
import sounddevice as sd
import soundfile as sf
filename = 'text.wav'
data, fs = sf.read(filename, dtype='float32')  
sd.default.device = '36'
sd.play(data, fs)
status = sd.wait()
```

Are there any solutions to this?

Comment: Playing through a microphone doesn't make sense since it's an input device. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: I want it to play a mp3/wav file that goes through VB audio cable. As of now I have tried that but it doesn’t allow inputs only outputs