# I want to send the audio I'm listening to on my computer through the microphone

Tags: python, speech-recognition

We're creating code that translates audio from YouTube in live. I want to send the audio I'm listening to on my computer through the microphone. What should I do?

```
import speech_recognition
import pyaudio
import speech_recognition as sr
from speech_recognition import *
import os
import googletrans

translator = googletrans.Translator()

r = Recognizer()
m = Microphone()

voice_data = 0

while 1 == True:
    with m as source:                           #음성인식
        audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            Text = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en')
            result = translator.translate(Text, dest='ko')
            print(result.text)
        except:
            print("can't recognitize")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Playing mp3 file through microphone with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37055745/playing-mp3-file-through-microphone-with-python)

Comment: I want to recognize the voice of the YouTube video that is playing, not the mp3 file.

Comment: it's the same principle, just different input. The re-routing should be the same after you get your audio input.

Comment: Can I translate videos into 'live' in that way?

Comment: what 'live' do you have in mind?

Comment: For example, you want to create a code that translates YouTube broadcasts(live stream) in live. (Did I understand your comment properly?)

Comment: do you need it done with python? There already are programs that do the task you are after: https://superuser.com/questions/603294/is-there-a-program-that-allows-me-to-send-audio-output-to-a-microphone-input-ei